# Reverse list of words in a text string separated by comma

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data in excel column like this
**Astronomy & Astrophysics; Physics, Nuclear; Physics, Particles & Fields**
I just want to reverse list of words in a text string separated by comma like the following
**Astronomy & Astrophysics; Nuclear Physics ; Particles & Fields Physics**

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in Astronomy & Astrophysics. I can tell how to do it for other strings.

- copy the data into excel.
  Go to data> text to columns> select delimited> select other> input " ," in the box now you see nuclear physics and particle fields are separated in different cells.
- LCopy those cells and paste as transpose, now it is arranged in rows.
  replace all charectors such as "&", ";" as ","
  select again data> text to columns> select delimited> select other> input >","
- Now data will be seprated in different cells.
- Use concatenate formula to arrange the strings as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This would be better done with VBA, but if done without I suppose a monster such as this could solve this issue if all your lines would have the same number of of commas and semicolons:

Your text in cell A1:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1)&MID(A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+2,FIND(",",A1,1)-FIND(",",A1,1)-2)&MID(A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1,FIND(",",A1,1)-FIND(",",A1,1)-1)&" ,"&MID(A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1))&MID(A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1)+1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1)-FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1)-1)
```